# Photos taking up storage on iPhone when I have no photos

Tags: iphone, photos, storage, ios

Problem from iOS 10.1.1 to 10.2.1.

I have no photos at all on my iPhone yet in settings it says my photo library is taking up ~200MB of space. The number of space being taken up keeps changing constantly(in the settings app on my phone). In iTunes, the storage bar at the bottom does(when in the sync menu) not show photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What is taking up this storage, and how can I reduce it?

### Troubleshooting:

- I disabled iCloud photo library and iCloud photo stream, still showing the same thing.
- Tried doing what @User9125 said, didn't work. I had set the date all the way back when I first got my phone, nothing showed up.
- Rebooting
- I had hundreds of photos in Whatsapp, I deleted them but I didn't get the storage back. It didn't even make a dent in the amount of storage being used by Photos so I don't think a third-party app could be taking up this storage.
- I don't think a system app is taking this space either, because I cleared the pictures in mail and messages.
- I tried using [iCleaner](http://www.redmondpie.com/download-icleaner-pro-on-ios-10-no-jailbreak-required/)(through sideloading) in Secure Mode and Fast Mode, but it did not clear up the photos.

Comment: @Peter that was my suggestion! Try turning it off, it'll probably clear up that storage as Peter hinted (please see my answer).

Comment: Can you try the suggestion I give in my answer (turning off iCloud Photo Library on your phone) and report back whether it works or not?

Comment: Hmm. Try backing up to iCloud, factory resetting, then restoring data from iCloud.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the only way, but it won't take too long to try. Not even sure it'll work.

Comment: Do you have an app like WhatsApp that might download photos onto your phone but keep them in that app's data instead of in the photo library? My point is, it's probably not wasted space.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe photos/videos in a system app like Messages or Mail then?

Comment: Ok then, so definitely try factory resetting your phone and restoring it from a backup.

Comment: You can do an iCloud backup anywhere you have Wifi (and your phone's probably already doing it automatically), but ok.

Comment: Doesn't iOS purge files with a lazy algorithm. How much free space is on the device? It might be temporary space waiting for a reason to purge. Seems odd and a bug if that space persists for weeks on end after the things you have tried.

Comment: Had over 2GB of „phantom“ data. Enabled iCloud Photos, waited until it said „finished“ and then disabled. Now down to around 200MB.

Maybe it‘s also showing the space the Photos app itself uses for its internal database and stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restore your device through itunes

Comment: @books453 With a similar issue that was my only option. Upload your photos to the iCloud Library. Then Make a backup, do a clean install and finally restore from backup. Photos should come back when signing into iCloud.

Answer (score 2):

There might be phantom photos still in your Photos app. Just do these things and it will solve your problem.

1. Go to Settings
2. Date & Time
3. Untoggle "Set Automatically"
4. Manually change the date back. For example, today is December 10, 2016, choose something ex: like March 21, 2015. (You can change it back once we're done)
5. Close out of that
6. Open "Photos"
7. Select "Albums" you had already cleared out everything from the Camera Roll and "Recently Deleted" folder, But now you'll see that your "Recently Deleted" folder now has thousands of images back. Those are your phantom photos
8. Open it, "Select" and start deleting
9. Now, go back into Settings - General - Usage - Storage - Manage Storage - and you'll notice your Photo & Camera is empty if you deleted everything.

Comment: This sounds plausible.. We will know for sure when the OP tested it.

Comment: @books453 did you select date as I mentioned? Could you please do the same for 2014 September 1st ? I don't know why the exact date matters but that would show phantom photos if there exist some.

Comment: According to some sources that happens because iOS couldn't delete images of Recently Deleted folder after 30 days. It does show images have already been deleted but actually they aren't. So it is better if you can consider some suitable year and month to select when changing the date since you haven't mentioned your iPhone Model. Ex : if you have an iPhone 6S it is useless to select date in 2014 since your photos (Phantom) simply didn't exist that time. So please select one more carefully. Hope to hear a good news

Comment: Same problem here. This solution didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Did not work for me on iOS 13.4.1. Tried with various fake dates from 3 years in the past in circa 2 months steps until reaching the present, and having explicitly quitted Photos.app (app switcher, slide up) inbetween those steps. "Recently deleted" always remained empty. Did not get the phantom pictures.

Comment: @porg This post is from 2016 and I think Apple has fixed that issue in later releases. I'm not quite sure why that happens in your mobile. Hope you will find the solution soon :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and no date/time tricks or whatever I found on the Internet worked for me. I managed to finally find and remove the photos using **iExplorer** application. Here is the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGaR9hglCJ0).
The app is not free but you can run it in demo mode and still find and remove the hidden photos.

Answer (score -1):

[iCloud Photo Library](http://www.apple.com/icloud/photos/) stores the photos you take in iCloud automatically and then stores lower-quality versions on your phone. I think you might have photos stored in this service, which could be causing storage usage of photos on your phone even if they aren't showing up locally on your phone.

Try turning off iCloud Photo Library if you have it on, as I think this is what is causing the storage usage of photos on your device. Go to `Settings` -> `iCloud` -> `Photos` and try turning iCloud Photo Library off; I suspect this will free up the megabytes of storage.

Answer (score -1):

Last week I was annoyed by my iPhone 6 16GB which was low on available storage. I connected the iPhone to my macbook, started iTunes and synced the iPhone without changing any of the settings. After syncing, I had 1.5 GB available storage.

I do not know how this could have helped, maybe it set some huge caches straight, but it could also be a solution for you.

Answer (score -2):

Reboot iPhone that (usually) clears the ghost data

Comment: I tried rebooting, didn't work.